# Проблемы при скачивании из Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Произошел релиз приложения. Доступно оно с android 4.0. У меня **Nexus 5** (**6.0.1 version**). 
При тестировании на разных устройствах(более 40 с разными версиями) не возникло проблем. Сотрудник(**HTC M8(6.0 android)**) скачал приложение и оно у него постоянно вылетает.
Начал тестировать.
Запустил дебаг - **запустилось**, запустил релиз версию - **запустилось**, запустил подписанный apk release версии - **ЗАПУСТИЛОСЬ**, а с Google Play - **никак**.
Если кто-то знает или сталкивался с данной проблемой напишите возможную причину и, если есть, решение. Сотрудники забыли уже, а мне до сих пор интересно.

Comment: пускай *сотрудник* отправит отчет о краше через гугл плей, стактрейс появится у вас в консоли разработчика. Или добавьте в приложение, например, гугл аналитику - она собирает все краши без отправки стактрейсов.